# $firebaseObject: Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am implementing [$firebaseObject](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-objects.html) in my code. However, when I include `$firebaseObject` as a dependency in my controller (or service), I immediately receive the following Angular [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=):

```
Unknown provider:
```

My controller:

```
angular.module('myapp.controllers-account', [])


.controller('AccountCtrl', 
  function($firebaseObject, $state, $anchorScroll, $location, $rootScope, $stateParams,
    OtherDependencies) {


    var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
    // download physicsmarie's profile data into a local object
    // all server changes are applied in realtime
    $scope.profile = $firebaseObject(ref.child('profiles').child('phsyicsmarie'));


})
```

Removing the dependency, fixes the issue. What is going on?

Note: I have put `firebase` as a dependency in my module, as I am using it on other places and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register `firebase` as a module with angular app.

```
angular.module('myapp.controllers-account', ["firebase"])
```

[Refrences](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html?gclid=COKarImlzsgCFQgnjgodJ_oLAQ)

Comment: Yes that has been done. I need to register it two times (controller and app.js)?